# How to Import SQL Files (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

It seems that whenever I tried to import an SQL file from D:\src\database\files\books.sql using the command from command line

source D:\src\database\files\books.sql;

It failed, the error said that it failed to open the file. But when I tried to import the SQL file directly from D:\books.sql;

source D:\books.sql;

It works fine.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

The following are the command lines used to import the SQL file

```
mysql -u root -p books

use books;
database changed

source D:\books.sql;
```

It worked

Now when I tried to put the file in another folder, for example, D:\src\database\files

I decided to create another database named listing and import the SQL file to this database

```
CREATE DATABASE listing;
use listing;
source D:\src\database\files\books.sql;
```

It didn't work

failed to open the file

Comment: Where is your command to import sql file ?

Comment: 1.Post the code
2.Post the entire error stack

Comment: Possible duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846879/import-sql-file-by-command-line-in-windows-7

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it:

```
mysql -u username -p databasename < somefile.sql
```

Note: You will be prompted for the password.

Comment: It gave me an error saying ERROR unknown table authors

Comment: I found the error, when I open the SQL file, I found this line DROP TABLE authors; in the first line. Since there is no table named authors in my database, it is very reasonable that it gave me an error when I tried to import the file

Comment: @AdityaBagas if you don't mind you can comment or delete that line.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL ,you can use the command

```
>>mysql -u username -password=<your_mysql_password> database_name < books.sql
```

There are various mysql GUI client tools like **sqlyog**, where-in you can import the data from CSV,sql,Excel formats without writing arduous commands. It just executes the sql file into the selected database.

Answer (score 0):

use as per below-

```
Go to command prompt and connect mysql
CREATE DATABASE listing;
use listing;
source D:/src/database/files/books.sql;
```